# Can I see if 2 commits patches are the same

Tags: git

If one branch have commits A-B-C and another branch have commits A-C'-B',
is there some way to make a hash of the patches of B and B'?
I want to (script a) compare of 2 branches, and report the differences, so in the case above I want it to notice they are the same.
If I use log between C and B' will show 2 commits, even if they are the same commits in another order.

Tested to do some diffs betweens `git show`, but as the line numbers differs, and I don't know how to get them to be equal.

Here is a script to set up a git test-case:

```
git init
seq 1 50 > a
git add a
git commit -m "fill a"

git checkout -b top_bottom
sed -i '1 a\
Add this line high up in the file' a
git add a
git commit -m "top of a"
sed -i '$ a\
Add this line at the bottom of the file' a
git add a
git commit -m "bottom of a"
git checkout master

git checkout -b bottom_top
git cherry-pick top_bottom
git cherry-pick top_bottom~
git checkout master
```

Doing a compare like `diff <(git show --format=raw top_bottom) <(git show --format=raw  bottom_top~1)` show line-number diffs in the patch part (and expected hashes differences in the header)

Comment: What about `git diff top_bottom bottom_top~`?

Comment: @choroba that going to show the content of top_bottom~, as it compares the branches, not just the commits

Comment: What do you mean by " it compares the branches, not just the commits"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If I have the commits A-B-C in one branch, and the commits A-C'-B' in another, and do `diff B B'`, then it compares A-B with A-C'-B', and finds that the difference are the content of C'.

Comment: So try cherry-picking just B' onto A in a new branch and compare against it?

Comment: @choroba works on this small case, my real case have over 100 commits diff between the branches, and at least half of them are duplicates, so that's why I want to make some kind of hash for each commit, that I can compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You want `git patch-id`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html), which is designed for exactly this purpose.

I had to modify your setup script slightly for FreeBSD `sed` (change `sed -i '1a\` to `sed -i -e '1a\`) but having done so:

```
$ git show bottom_top | git patch-id --stable
3a28b42e4aae9c248c00c63451756cbd881cf046 2c33ad0a41076e5a47ec780e8ab6c6b8450db582
$ git show top_bottom~1 | git patch-id --stable
3a28b42e4aae9c248c00c63451756cbd881cf046 7cd871013b7bbfc69f03315d43285a2b78b81a86
```

The first number is the patch ID (you may use either `--stable` or `--unstable`; read the documentation to decide which to use) and the second is the commit hash.  Note that `top_bottom` produces a different patch ID (from, of course, a different commit):

```
$ git show top_bottom | git patch-id --stable
69febc37e58b8aeb210b3e1e71fa59a11c369a74 9a34efdfe098f6b690199a124cc3ce34f48002b8
```

Comment: I remember reading something like that a while ago, but couldn't find it, thanks, it shows that top_bottom = bottom_top~, and bottom_top = top_bottom~, nice

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to do this sort of thing en-masse, note that `git rev-list L...R --cherry` (see also `--cherry-mark` and `--right-only`) enumerates all the commits in a symmetric difference, computes all of their patch IDs, and then marks commits in its output. The lower level patch-id lets you save this sort of information rather than recompute it, and is more flexible but more work.

Answer (score 2):

To compare patches, I would rather use `git diff` :

```
git diff B^ B > B.patch
```

Taking back your example :

```
# name B1 and B2 the 2 commits you want to inspect :
git tag B1 top_bottom^
git tag B2 bottom_top
```

Get the pacthes :

```
# first patch :
git diff B1^ B1 > B1.patch
# second patch :
git diff B2^ B2 > B2.patch
```

The blunt comparison will still show the differences in line numbers :

```
diff B1.patch B2.patch
```

An approximation would be : drop the lines mentionning line numbers, and see if the simple "added / removed" blocks match :

```
cat B1.patch |
  grep -v "^index" |  # remove lines which mention blob or tree hashes
  grep -v "^@@"       # remove lines which mention line numbers
    > B1.trimmed

# same with B2

diff B1.trimmed B2.trimmed
```

Comment: A diff between the tree/branch B' and the tree/branch B are going to show the content of C', as a git diff compares tree's, I just want to compare the commits.

Comment: (after your edit), so with the greps you suggested, I could do the oneliner: `diff <(git show --format=format:patch top_bottom | grep -v "^index" | grep -v "^@@") <(git show --format=format:patch  bottom_top~ | grep -v "^index" | grep -v "^@@")`

Comment: comparable hash values should then be `git show --format=format:patch bottom_top~ | sed -e "s/^@@.*@@.*/@@ (line numbers)/" -e "s/index .* /index (from..to) /" | shasum`

Comment: Yes, should do. Add the leading `^` in your second sed command (otherwise you would potentially scrap any row with "index" in it).

Comment: I noticed i wanted to exclude some paths, so the patch-id doesn't work in my real use case, so ended up writing the script from your sugestions: https://pastebin.com/wEAa9nhT